# Не понимаю почему не проходит тесты

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, python-3.6

Президент Берляндии решил увековечить свое имя в истории. Решено было построить Великий Берляндский Забор. Забор представляет собой последовательность вертикально расположенных досок. Каждая доска имеет ширину 1 метр. Всего в Заборе n досок, высота i-й доски в Заборе равна hi метров (i=0…n−1). Главный конструктор сделал чертеж забора. Ваша задача найти периметр Великого Берляндского Забора на полученном чертеже.

Входные данные
В первой строке входных данных записано целое положительное число n — количество досок в Заборе (1≤n≤1000). Во второй строке содержится последовательность n целых положительных чисел h0,h1,…,hn−1, записанных через пробел. hi обозначает высоту i-й доски в Заборе (1≤hi≤100).

Выходные данные
Выведите искомый периметр в метрах.

Примеры
входные данные

2

1 2

выходные данные

8

входные данные

1

1

выходные данные

4

входные данные

4

30 87 88 31

выходные данные

184

```py
n= int (input())
a=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
p=0
for i in range (-1,1,n+1):
  p=a[0]*4+(a[1]*4-2)+(a[i+1]*4-((i+1*2)-2))
print(p)
```

[image: примечание, пояснение к первому примеру]

примечание, пояснение к первому примеру

Comment: `range(-1,1,n+1)` - очень странная вещь. Разберитесь с этим.

Answer (score 2):

Не очень знаю python, но вы считаете что-то не то...

```
n = int(input())
p = 0
last = 0
for i in range(0,n):

    m = int(input())

    p = p + abs(m-last)
    last = m
p = p + last + n*2
print(p)
```

Вот тут -

```
    m = int(input())
```

просто не знаю, как там правильно читать последовательно числа из ввода, сами подправьте...

Короче - вам нужно суммировать нижнюю горизонтальную часть забора (`n`), верхнюю (`n`), высоты первой и последней досок забора, а также разности высот соседних досок по модулю (абсолютной величине). Все.

Comment: последний тест не проходит 4     30 87 88 31

Comment: Почему не проходит? Вот - 184: https://ideone.com/QJO3u3

Comment: Не проходит, потому что в m несколько чисел сразу должно вводиться, а если меняешь, то уже программа не проходит.

Comment: Уважаемая, я же написал: *Вот тут -

    m = int(input())

просто не знаю, как там правильно читать последовательно числа из ввода, сами подправьте...* Если уж вы Python не знаете, то почему его должен знать я? :) Вам нужно понять или сдать? Вы хотите, не приложив усилий даже для понимания, тупо скопировать и взять пирожок с полки? обидно...